# MSHTML: Is there a way to attach events or behaviors to an element after Drag/Drop or Paste?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, webbrowser-control, mshtml

I'm working with the WebBrowser control, using the DesignMode function for editing HTML. I'm using the MSHTML interfaces in order to look at and modify the DOM.

Take for example an input text box - I can attach an event sink using the connection point, or add a custom rendering behavior, but when I move this input box to another part of the document, I lose both the connection point hook, and the behavior that was added.

Is there any kind of event I can hook up to in which I can connect the event sink and re-add the behavior?

Comment: are you looking for something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090754/c-sharp-web-browser-with-click-and-highlight functionality?

Comment: @volody- Not necessarily, the issue is when a user interaction moves an element, any events or decorations that were applied to the original element are not retained in the new one.

Comment: Tried using the IHTMLEditDesigner interface, but the associated events (drop/paste) don't seem to be invoked here. Added a hack to get this working in the mean time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any events to hook on to for when elements are deleted or created by the control, I did find an event that will fire when any changes are made (including by the control itself): [IHTMLChangeSink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa704257%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

This interface has one method "Notify()" which fires whenever the document changes.

Hooking up the event to the class implementing this interface:

```
        var markupContainer = _document as IMarkupContainer2;
        if(markupContainer != null)
        {
            uint tmpCookie = 0;
            markupContainer.RegisterForDirtyRange(this, out tmpCookie);
            _changeSinkCookie = tmpCookie;
        }
```

I keep a list of elements that are in the document, and then diff when this event fires to tell if any elements were added or removed.